# get variable values from string

Tags: php

I am fetching some API data with cURL and it returns the output in following string:

```
$response = "oauth_token=xxx&oauth_token_secret=yyy&oauth_expires_in=3600&xoauth_request_auth_url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.login.yahoo.com%2Foauth%2Fv2%2Frequest_auth%3Foauth_token%3Dxxx&oauth_callback_confirmed=true";
```

How can I get the values for each of the key from the above string, for example I want to get the `xoauth_request_auth_url` value. Currently I'm doing it in following way:

```
$arr = explode('&', $response);

$url = $arr[3];     
$url = explode('=', $url);

$xoauth_request_auth_url = $url[1]; //final result
```

**My questions:**

1. Is there an efficient way to get the above value (I'm afraid above method will not work if there's an `&` in any of the variable vlaue)?
2. How can I convert the URl value into url format? For example currently it is:

`https%3A%2F%2Fapi.login.yahoo.com`

I would like to convert it into:

`https://api.login.yahoo.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parse_str()` to parse a URL query string into an array and `urldecode()` to get the decoded characters:

```
parse_str($response, $array);
$array = array_map('urldecode', $array);

print_r($array);
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [oauth_token] => xxx
    [oauth_token_secret] => yyy
    [oauth_expires_in] => 3600
    [xoauth_request_auth_url] => https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/request_auth?oauth_token=xxx
    [oauth_callback_confirmed] => true
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [**parse_str**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php), like so:

```
$values = array();
parse_str($response, $values);
var_dump($values);
```

Also, if you need to remove the URL encoded characters from any of the values, use [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php).

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

or you can build your own function (i can give you guidelines should parse-str not cover your needs)

as for your second question,it also answers part of the first. Uri components are being encoded and therefore you will not find (or should not find) an actual & character. Like wise to decode url's. use
http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php
and to encode its function pair urlencode